# SQL Anywhere 17 and PHP functions: sasql_disconnect vs sasql_close

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

I'm using PHP to connect to a SQL Anywhere 17 database.
One of two commands can be used to close the connection.
sasql_disconnect or sasql_close.

At https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp I can find very brief information that:
**sasql_disconnect**: Closes a connection that has been opened with sasql_connect or sasql_pconnect.
**sasql_close**: Closes a previously opened database connection.

Both functions take the same type of parameters and return true or false.

There is no information on the above page about the differences between the two functions.
There is also no information that the reason for the existence of one of them was the desire to maintain compatibility with previous versions of the database.

Still, I suspect there is a reason for the existence of the two functions.
Does anyone know how they differ? When to use one and when the other?
Thank you.
Marcin.

Comment: Both functions are described to do the same thing so does it matter if they internally work differently? I wouldn't think so. Finding resources is going to be a problem when using software that's 8 years old at this point.

Answer (score -1):

My assumption is that they **are** identical, and there is no functional difference between them.

The verb "disconnect" seems to be the canonical one, i.e. the one normally used. When looking at implementations in other languages, those examples exclusively use `disconnect`. For example, [their Ruby library](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.11.0.1/dbprogramming_en11/pg-ruby-disconnect.html).

Meanwhile, PHP mostly uses the "close" verb. At least in both `mysqli_close()` and `pg_close()`. So it makes sense to follow the same convention when writing a PHP library, as it will be the function name most developers would expect.

Because of these conflicting standards, having aliases for functions would make sense. Especially in a language like PHP, which has many [function aliases](https://www.php.net/manual/en/aliases.php) already.

Comment: This is not a normal mysql server. SQL Anywhere 17 is a commercial RDBMS developed by SAP. So we need to use separate module in php for this. To connect to SQL Anywhere 17 from PHP, you need to use the SQL Anywhere PHP module, also known as sasql_connect.

Comment: I know? Please read my answer again, you have completely misinterpreted my words.

Answer (score -2):

**sasql_disconnect** and **sasql_close** are functions used to manage database connections. While they serve similar purposes, there are some differences between them:

**sasql_disconnect**: This function is used to terminate the connection to a database. When you call **sasql_disconnect**, it will close the connection established with the database server and release any associated resources. It essentially ends the session with the database, and you cannot execute any further SQL statements until you establish a new connection.

**sasql_close**: This function is used to close a specific cursor or result set that you have obtained from executing a SQL query. In SAS, when you execute a SQL query using sasql_exec_direct or sasql_prepare, you usually retrieve the results into a cursor. After you have finished working with the result set, you need to close the cursor using sasql_close to release the resources associated with it.

To summarize, **sasql_disconnect** is used to terminate the entire database connection, while **sasql_close** is used to close a specific cursor or result set within an active connection.